# Gulp + karma + jasmine + angular + singleRun:true = angular fails to inject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an issue when running Jasmine tests through Karma and Gulp, I'm running tests through a gulp task with

```
return new karma.Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '\\karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
}, done).start();
```

Which fails on my angular dependency injection, I get a standard angular `unknown provider myProvider` error. When I change the `singleRun` property to `false`, most of the unit tests pass (one set still fails though).

The tests have (and still) work fine in Chutzpah.

I've tried reducing my tests to the barebones:

```
var myProvider;
beforeEach(module('MyModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_my_) {
    myProvider = _my_;
}));

it("exists", function () {
    expect(myProvider).not.toBeUndefined();
});
```

and it still fails with the `unknown provider myProvider` error. Again, they run fine if I set `singleRun` to `false`. I've tried running PhantomJS and Chrome, they both show the exact same behavior.

I'm using angular 1.4.7 and my dependencies in package.json look like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-chug": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.19",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.23",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2"
  }
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ["jasmine"],
        reporters: ["spec"],
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        files: [
            "./path/to/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",

            "./path/to/angular/angular.js",
            "./path/to/angular/angular-route.js",
            "./path/to/angular/angular-mocks.js",

            // I'm using this path order (app -> modules -> all) 
            // due to recommendations found on SO
            "./path/to/application/app.js",
            "./path/to/application/**/*Module.js",
            "./path/to/application/**/*.js",

            // For now, I'm just running the one test to simplify debugging
            "./path/to/tests/myTest.Test.js"
        ]
    });
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that our custom angular providers had internal dependencies that for some reason weren't being resolved with `singleRun: true`.

I specifically set the load order for these files in karma.conf so that the dependencies load in the "correct" order and now I get the same result as when running with `singleRun:false` (the same few tests as with `singleRun:false` still fail, but that's another story).

The reason this worked with Chutzpah was that those references (which were listed in each individual test file) were in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Your Karma conf looks far too bare. You need to define preprocessors in karma conf. You need to preload your Angular Javascript files. You should also preload HTML files. You will prob wanna preload angular mocks too if testing HTTP. This should give you a headstart. Any specific questions please ask.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage'],
    singleRun: true,
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/!(*spec)*.js': ['coverage'],
      'dest/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'dest/',
      moduleName: 'ngHtmlFiles'
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'html',
      dir: 'coverage'
    },
    files: [
      'dest/vendor.min.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'src/**/*.js',
      'dest/**/*.html'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: I haven't posted my karma.conf, it looks pretty much like the one you posted though. Like I said, everything loads and works, including angular, as long as the singleRun property isn't true. Why would I want to load HTML files? I don't see how my views would be relevant to my tests and logic at all? I don't currently have any directive tests, if that's what you're referring to. I can post my karma.conf tomorrow though, I just didn't think it'd be relevant.

Comment: you want to load HTML files if testing HTTP because you make expectations concerning HTTP requests in your tests and if you dont preload HTML you have to expect all HTML file HTTP requests too, which isnt really what you want to be testing - you test HTTP using $httpBackend - this is when it become relevant

Comment: Ok, I don't really see the utility, but we're not doing that. I am using httpbackend, but to mock AJAX service requests. In those cases I mock and resolve those manually in the tests. We don't do any actual requests to any HTML files at all. And they wouldn't resolve to a HTML file in any case. I'll post an example karma.conf in a bit.